# how to view an users public list of sharing in torrent?

Tags: bittorrent

how to view an users public list of sharing in torrent?

For example if particular user is sharing x.pdf and he might also would share other pdf. How to get those list and dowload?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The torrent protocol does not allow for this. Torrents are controlled by trackers. The tracker can possibly tell you which files are being served by the same IP address, but that is not their purpose. This is why, in order to shut down a torrent site, they need to shut down the tracker as well as the site hosting the torrent files.

Answer (score 0):

you can't.

bit torrent doesn't work like other P2P networks where you can browse shared folders of other users.